# Can a rmtree command with an onerror function be used within a try/except statement?

Tags: python, shutil, try-except, onerror

I've been trying to find an answer pertaining to how error handling and propagation are handled when using the `shutil.rmtree` command *inside* a try/except statement. I've tried to find an example showing such a practice, but have not been able to find one. So, I'm left wondering if it's even possible. When reading the documentation for the command [here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html) I see that it states:

> ...to remove a directory tree on Windows where some of the files have
>   their read-only bit set. It uses the onerror callback to clear the
>   readonly bit and reattempt the remove. Any subsequent failure will
>   propagate.

Doesn't this mean that if an error occurs *within* the `onerror` function after the initial try to execute the `onerror` function, in other words the `onerror` function doesn't fix the error and it occurs when the `shutil.rmtree` tries to run again, that the error will be raised in the main routine (where the try/except statement is)? Is that what it means by "Any subsequent failure will propagate"?

I'm trying to make sure that if for whatever reason any of the `shutil.rmtree` commands fail that the failure will be caught and the code will still continue. I have another script that run after this script to check/correct errors in batches, which is why I'm not directly handling the errors. I just need to make sure this script runs all the way through. Will the code below accomplish this as it's written or is there anything that I need to change to accomplish this?

```
import shutil
import os
import stat

def remove_readonly(func, path, excinfo):
    os.chmod(path, stat.S_IWRITE)
    func(path)

try:
    #os.chmod is used to turn off Read-Only attribute
    os.chmod("Q:/-----.vbs", stat.S_IWRITE)
    #os.remove is used to remove individual files
    os.remove("Q:/-----.vbs")
except:
    pass

#shutil.rmtree is used to remove entire directories
#remove traces of file
try:
    shutil.rmtree("Q:/FolderToRemove1", onerror=remove_readonly)
except:
    pass

try:
    shutil.rmtree("Q:/FolderToRemove2", onerror=remove_readonly)
except:
    pass

try:
    shutil.rmtree("Q:/FolderToRemove3", onerror=remove_readonly)
except:
    pass

try:
    shutil.rmtree("Q:/FolderToRemove4", onerror=remove_readonly)
except:
    pass

try:
    shutil.rmtree("Q:/FolderToRemove5", onerror=remove_readonly)
except:
    pass

try:
    shutil.rmtree("C:/Users/mhill/Desktop/screenshots", onerror=remove_readonly)
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) states that *exceptions raised by onerror will not be caught*, thus you must handle it yourself.

In terms of your sample code, a blank `except` is generally poor design.  In particular, it will also catch a `KeyboardInterrupt` which is surely not your intent.

Rather, something like this:

```
for f in ["Q:/FolderToRemove1", "Q:/FolderToRemove2", 
          "Q:/FolderToRemove3", "Q:/FolderToRemove4", 
          "Q:/FolderToRemove5", "C:/Users/mhill/Desktop/screenshots"]:
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(f, onerror=remove_readonly)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Comment: I must've missed that pieced, thanks for pointing that out. Also, thanks for the more streamlined version of my code. Since I'd have to handle any errors in the 'onerror' function myself how would I have any error that occurs in the 'onerror' function bubble back up to the try/except statement and trigger the 'pass'?

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder any naturally occurring exception will bubble up through the stack frames until it finds a handler ...

Comment: Gotcha, the first part of your answer confused me at first. So, if I use the streamlined bit of code you provided and the `remove_readonly` function as it is now all errors that occur in that function will be handled by the `except` statement? I just want to clarify that because when you said "naturally occurring" errors. What constitutes a natural error and an unnatural one?

Comment: Could you explain/answer my above questions please? Once you do I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder Just ignore the fact I used the word "naturally" ... any exception will bubble up through the stack frames until it finds a handler.